# Is there some special name for console in win32?

Tags: winapi, console

I want to open console with **CreateFile** for writing with function **WriteFile**.

In unix-like systems there is special device in /dev/ directory, so i can open it with **open**.

I want similar behavior under win32 (maybe there is some special name for console).

P.S. I know about **hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);**, i want to open console with **CreateFile**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `AllocConsole`/`OpenConsole` first, then call `GetStdHandle` to get a `HANDLE` you can pass to `WriteFile`.

Or you can use `CreateFile("CON", GENERIC_WRITE, ...)`, which is also mentioned in the documentation for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i wrote that i know this way, i need to open console with **CreateFile**